# Android ImagePicker

Tags: android, imageview

I wrote a code to pick images in Android and copied certain pics to res/drawable folder after creating the drawable folder, without duplicating the contents to other drawable folders.

Here's my code.

***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.imagepicker.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPick"
        android:onClick="pickImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="Load Image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnPick"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.imagepicker;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //Image loading result to pass to startActivityForResult method
    public static final int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //GUI components
    private Button button; //the button
    private ImageView image; //the imageview

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Find references to the GUI objects
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPick);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        //Set button's onClick listener object
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //create the intent for ImageGallery
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                i.setType("image/*");

                //Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT to handle back the result when the image is picked from the Image Gallery
                startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);      
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        InputStream ImageStream = null;

        /*Checking if the activity that was triggered was the ImageGallery
          If so then requestCode will match the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS value
          If the resultCode is RESULT_OK &
          There is some data that we know that image was picked*/
        if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                //Let's read the picked image -its URI
                Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

                //Let's read the image path using content resolver
                ImageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage);

                //Now let's set the GUI ImageView data with data read from the picked file
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ImageStream);
            }

            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                if (ImageStream != null) {
                    try {
                        ImageStream.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running, when I click on the button to load images, I get a message "***NO MEDIA FOUND***".

What's wrong here? I've copied the images to res/drawable folder and not to other drawable folders. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**NO MEDIA FOUND** means there is no picture in your gallery. By placing any image in your device (phone) will solve this issue.

You are using following code to load/pick images.

```
//create the intent for ImageGallery
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType("image/*");
```

This **code will not load images** from res/drawable. It will load images from your device/gallery.

If you want to load images from drawable folder and want to pick one. Then it is your responsibility (writing code) to load images and pick (select) one

Comment: I'm using eclipse & am still studying Android development. How do I test image picker example? To which folder should i copy the images and where to re-write the code?

Comment: How you have to test your image picker example was just explained by pokerface: put some images in your phone. Or take some pictures or screenshots with it. /res/drawable or /assets folder is both ok to deliver your app with images. But before a user can pick them you have to copy the images to a place where the user and file picker have access.

Comment: Allright, I took the pictures, and upon clicking Load Images button, they do appear. But after selecting an image, it shows "Unfortunately ImagePicker has stopped" .What could be the error?

Answer (score 0):

You've set attribute android:onClick="pickImage" but there is not method pickImage in your Java code.

Comment: also you're not using bitmap factory without which you'll be unable to assign the photo

Comment: Your answer would be more constructive if you explained to the OP how they can fix the problem rather than just highlighting it for them. In addition further information should be edited into your answer rather than just being left as a comment.